# Can't find some font files on my rails app on production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

**Rails app, deployed to digitalocean**:
**Can't find font files**, 'entypo.ttf' and 'entypo.woff' **on production**.

Font files path: **app/assets/fonts**.

CSS code for the font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  src: url('/assets/entypo.eot?71205724');
  src: url('/assets/entypo.eot?71205724#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/assets/entypo.woff?71205724') format('woff'),
       url('/assets/entypo.ttf?71205724') format('truetype'),
       url('/assets/entypo.svg?71205724#entypo') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**On development environment everything works great.**

Any Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `asset-path` or `asset-url` instead of trying to link to the files directly. Your production environment is likely fingerprinting the files for you.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'entypo';
  src: asset-url('fonts/entypo.eot?71205724');
  src: asset-url('fonts/entypo.eot?71205724#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       asset-url('fonts/entypo.woff?71205724') format('woff'),
       asset-url('fonts/entypo.ttf?71205724') format('truetype'),
       asset-url('fonts/entypo.svg?71205724#entypo') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Make sure you read up on [the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)! Specifically the sub-section on [CSS and SASS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)

Comment: Thanks! it works when added 'asset-url' instead of 'url' but without passing 'fonts/' so for example: `src: asset-url('entypo.eot?71205724');`

Comment: @Mohammedk91 Yeah Rails can be smart enough to look in all the top level folders for you